# Error: Field larger than field limit (131072)

Tags: python, json, csv, data-conversion

I am using big csv data in spyder python to convert csv to json but it shows error field larger than field limit (131072).

Script for conversion:

```
import csv
import json


file = r'abcdata.csv'
json_file = r'abcdata.json'


#Read CSV File
def read_CSV(file, json_file):
    csv_rows = []
    with open(file) as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        field = reader.fieldnames
        for row in reader:
            csv_rows.extend([{field[i]:row[field[i]] for i in range(len(field))}])
        convert_write_json(csv_rows, json_file)


#Convert csv data into json
def convert_write_json(data, json_file):
    with open(json_file, "w") as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(data, sort_keys=False, indent=1, separators=(',', ': '))) #for pretty
        f.write(json.dumps(data))

read_CSV(file, json_file)
```

Comment: Please add the stacktrace. And also add some more data about the data you're using, row/column number, file size, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You must have large columns of data.  The default limit for the data in a single column is `csv.field_size_limit()`.  It can be changed:

```
>>> import csv
>>> csv.field_size_limit()
131072
>>> csv.field_size_limit(256<<10)
131072
>>> csv.field_size_limit()
262144
```

You could also be reading the .CSV incorrectly.